# Matrices are close if and only if null spaces are close

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n \times m$ matrices with $n < m$. Assume $AG=BG=I_n$ (the identity matrix of dimension $n \times n$), where $G$ is an $m \times n$ matrix (with $Rank(G)=n$), and assume that $A H =0$, where $H$ is an $m \times (m-n)$ matrix and $0$ is an $n\times(m-n) $ matrix of $0$'s, and $Rank(H)=m-n$. Show that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that

$$
||AH-BH||< \delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad ||A-B||<\varepsilon.
$$
where $||\cdot||$ is the operator norm.
In words, if the null space of $A$ and the null space of $B$ are close then $A$ and $B$ are close.

**Edit:** I made some updates to reflect what I wanted from the question (specifically, $||AH-BH||< \delta \quad \Leftarrow \quad ||A-B||<\varepsilon$ is immediate). I will post my solution now. Any comments /confirmation is appreciated.

Comment: If $Rank(H)=m-n$, and $||H||=1$, then we require the strict inequality $n<m$.

Comment: thanks, updated.... if $n=m$ the result is immediate since $A=B=G^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(G,H)$ is nonsingular because of the rank nullity theorem. Then,

\begin{align*}
||A-B||&=||[A(G,H)-B(G,H)](G,H)^{-1}||\\
&=||[(I_n,0)-(I_n,BH)](G,H)^{-1}||\\
&=||(0,BH)(G,H)^{-1}||\\
&\leq ||BH||\cdot||(G,H)^{-1}||\\
&=||AH-BH||\cdot||(G,H)^{-1}||
\end{align*}